# sounddriver with aplay/arecord works fine not with another application

Tags: linux, driver, alsa, pjsip

I wrote an I2S sound driver for the Raspberry Pi. I looks like it works fine.
With alsa-aplay I can playback some music and with alsa-arecord I can record some sound which sounds great!

Now, the thing is.. I crosscompiled a simple application with the pjproject/pjsip with the aim of using the Raspberry Pi as a softphone. Some additional info: I build my own kernel (angstrom distribution) and rootfs with Openembedded, also with PJproject included.
PJproject has some test-applications and one of them (pjsystest) am I using to simply test if my sounddriver works fine.  and it doesn't..

The pjsysstest had some different test options like, Play a Tone and Record Audio.
Through debbugging I can conclude that when I start to play a tone option, the next callbacks are called.
- PCM playback open 
- PCM playback hw params
- PCM playback prepare
- PCM playback trigger (start)
**- PCM playback trigger (stop)
- PCM playback prepare**

Using just aplay:
- PCM playback open 
- PCM playback hw params
- PCM playback prepare
- PCM playback trigger (start)
//when the file is at the end:
- PCM playback trigger (stop)
- PCM playback hw free
- PCM playback close

Debugging with the pjsystest gives some strage results.
I don't understand why the trigger callbacks is called a second time to stop the stream and after that just the prepare callback is called (and not the trigger start callback aswell). Because of that there is no tune playing(because the playback stream is already stopted and nog started again).

Now, I hope you'll do understand what my problem is, and I hope someone can give me an answer or suggestion in the right direction too (or even better the solution).

Thanks a lot!

[edit]
In the meantime I tried some other PJproject sample applications: stereotest and auddemo. Those are actually working :) Thats good, this says (I think):
- nothing is wrong with my kernel and rootfs
- nothing is wrong with my driver.

The question now is: Why is the PJSYSTEST not working. Why does it calls the trigger start and then stops it directly ?

[/edit]

Comment: frame exact question whatever you are require..?? make it precise...!

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your driver, probably in the trigger callback, but it's impossible to tell without the source code.

Comment: @Inge Did you found solution ?